# Incompatible type double string

Tags: java, string, types, double

Why would purchase be an incompatible type for `scan.next()`? 
(I am trying to get the user input for purchase and tendered, and then use a method to calculate the change).

```
public static void makeChange() //one method of a class
{       
    double purchase;
    double tendered;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println ("How much was the Purchase?");
    purchase = scan.next(); //why would this be an incompatible type?
    System.out.println ("Amount Tendered"); 
    tendered = scan.next();      

    System.out.println("Processing Transaction");
    int ch[] = cd.makeChange(purchase, tendered);

    .... continued
```

Comment: Using `double` for monetary values is not an appropriate choice.

Comment: Isn't integer for digits without a decimal i.e 20
I was using double for a digit with decimals, i.e 20.00

Comment: BigDecimal has digits and does not lose them, too (which double does).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) returns a string as described in the javadoc. That's the first place to check when a method does not do what you think it should. You probably meant to use `scanner.nextDouble()`.

As pointed out in the comments, if your code is more than an exercise, you should use BigDecimal for monetary amounts to avoid rounding issues (doubles are not exact).